# ASP.NET client/browser URL

Tags: asp.net, localization, url-rewriting, globalization

I'm wondering how I can get the URL from the browser in ASP.NET.

I have a page that I use with globalization/localization, and I am redirecting (via server not code) from `www.spanishversion.com` to `www.englishversion.com`, but the URL is masked to still say `www.spanishversion.com`. I want to get what the browser's URL is but when I try things like:

- `Request.Url.ToString()`
- `Request.Url.OriginalUrl`
- `Request.Path Request.RawUrl`
- `Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]`

It always comes back as `www.englishversion.com`.  Is there a way that I can explicitly read the URL from the browser?

Comment: What sort of redirect are you doing?

If you're doing a Server.Transfer, then you're out of luck. But a Response.Redirect shouldn't cause the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Javascript, with [`location.href`](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_loc_href.asp).

Comment: Is there a way I could get to this from managed code?  I'm needing the url in .net so I can set the current culture

Comment: An ugly solution would be to first render a skeleton page that contains no localised content, then use AJAX on the client side that passes the location.href to the server, and the server can return the content to fill the rest of the page, which the client can do with .innerHTML. Not recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Request.Url.Host`

Comment: Tried that too.  www.englishverison.com is what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery.aspx)

I use it to set variables in a master page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
Request.Rawurl
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you got this situation wrong. You say the address bar is masked to show `www.spanishversion.com`, but is it showing `www.spanishversion.com` or not?